# using $.getJSON to retrieve php variable php

Tags: php, variables, mysqli, getjson

Hi I am currently trying out using `$.getJSON` to retrieve data from another php file. However I am kind of new to JSON so I am kind of missing stuffs here and there. Wonder if someone could help me fill in the blanks. Current I trying to get the details to be displayed in the console.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".login_a").click(function(){
    $("#shadow").fadeIn("normal");
    var test = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var topost = 'getMilestoneDetail.php='+test;
    var returnResults = $.getJSON('getMilestoneDetail.php?id='+test,function(data)
    {
        console.log(data.projectName + " " + data.budget);
    });      
});
</script>

$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM projectmilestone where ID = '$id' ";
$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
    $projectName =$row['projectName'] ;
    $budget = $row['budget'];
    $id = $row['ID'];
    $mile1 = $row['mileStone1'];
    $mile2 = $row['mileStone2'];
    $mile3 = $row['mileStone3'];
    $percent1 = $row['percentage1'];
    $percent2 = $row['percentage2'];
    $percent3 = $row['percentage3'];
}
echo json_encode($row);
```

Comment: Neither of your methods returns anything. You just get data. You need to look at json_encode and writing output.

Comment: Do you have any link or example that can show me?

Comment: this is going to seem pedantic, but http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: This may seem trivial, but you are connecting to your MySQL database right? The above code looks like it contains everything you're doing. Missing though, is your connection handler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE2**: since i guess you are only getting one result row, you won't need the while-loop at all. my bad since `$row` is not accesible from outside the loop. so just replace your while loop with:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

then you just need to output your first row which is `$row[0]`:

```
echo json_encode($row[0]);
```

this will put out a json string which looks like

```
{"projectName":"abc...", "budget":"12345", .... }
```

and so on.

in your javascript i don't know where your `POST` variable is. rather try your $.getJSON function with `GET` variable. plus (**update**) your json object is returned to the parameter "data" of the anonymous callback function:

```
$.getJSON('getMilestoneDetail.php?id=' + test, function(data)
{
    //your returned data is saved in the variable "data" which is passed in the anonymous function above
    console.log(data.projectName + " " + data.budget);
});
```

then you have to look for a get variable in your `PHP` script.
so replace:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

with:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

**UPDATE**: I've made changes to the javascript part, since it won't return anything otherwise.

Comment: I tried however in the console it is still empty. Currently the code looks like this

Comment: see my update on the javascript part. `$.getJSON` doesn't return the json object itself - it returns a `jqxhr` object. your json object is returned using the parameter "data" of the anonymous callback function.

Comment: If you type the url in your browser, using developer tools, what do you see coming back?

Comment: I have just updated it. However when i open the console is still empty. The codes I am currently running now is on top I updated it

Comment: @Ich you still haven't replaced `$id = $_POST['id'];` with `$id = $_GET['id'];`

Comment: Hmm now there is an error saying Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'projectName' of null. I think it cant get the value?

Comment: @Ich try my updated mysqli - query stuff. sorry for that mess, i just wanted to quickly help you and haven't tested it at all.

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much it is now able to call out the stuff!

Comment: @Ich just was about to setup some testing environment to chech it out myself ;) you are welcome!